# Rails 4.2 valid code or not?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

i've got the following code

```
def self.activate_lessons
i = 0
#for lesson in Lesson.to_activate
for lesson in Lesson.find :all, :conditions => ["start_date < ? AND (active <> ? OR active IS NULL)", DateTime.now, true]
  lesson.active = true
  lesson.save
  i += 1
  end
  i
end
```

is this a vaild rails 4.2 code or not?

I got this error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find all Lessons with 'id': (all, {:conditions=>["start_date < ? AND (active <> ? OR active IS NULL)", Sat, 02 Apr 2016 09:50:06 +0000, true]}) (found 0 results, but was looking for 2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Using this code:

```
Lesson.where("start_date < ? AND active = ?", DateTime.now,Nil).update_all(active: true)
```

Comment: got this error: syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting :: or '[' or '.'

Comment: was my mistake sorry. But Now I got this error: NameError: uninitialized constant Lesson::Nil

Comment: any Idea why it is nil?

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to activate lessons and return the number of lessons that has been activated you can do it like this

```
def self.activate_lessons
 Lesson.where.not(active: true).where("start_date < ?", DateTime.now).update_all(active: true)
end
```

> find(:first) and find(:all) support is removed from rails 3.2+.

Comment: This isn't quite equivalent since validations/callbacks won't be called.

Comment: You're right to call validations/callbacks he needs to instantiate objects (which is an expensive operation by the way), But i don't think model validations will be needed here since the value "true" is set explicitly and he can always trigger the wanted callback explicitly after the operation.

Comment: Who knows - there could easily be validations with `if: active?`